# R Shiny: object 'input' not found

Tags: r, shiny

This is a follow-up question from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554201/r-shiny-user-defined-function-works-well-in-regular-r-code-but-fails-inside-a-s/49565541#49565541) which was correctly answered by @K.Rohde. I am unable to call an input from UI as an argument in a user-defined function. Below is the complete reproducible shiny code:

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

rm(list = ls())

Aging <- function(data, Transaction.Date, Report.Date = Sys.Date()){
  if(missing(Transaction.Date)) stop("You forgot to specify Transaction Date")
  Transaction.Date <- deparse(substitute(Transaction.Date))
  Report.Date <- deparse(substitute(Report.Date))
  data$year <- year(data[,Transaction.Date])
  data$Age <- car::recode(year(data[,Transaction.Date]), paste0("year(", Report.Date, ") = year(", Report.Date, "); year(", Report.Date, ") - 1 = year(", Report.Date, ") - 1; else = paste(year(", Report.Date, ")-2, 'And Prior')"))
  return(data)
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  dateInput("Report.Date", "Enter Cut-off Date"),
  actionButton("Submit", "Submit"),
  dataTableOutput("Aged.Data")

)

server <- function(input, output) {




    Debtors <- eventReactive(input$Submit, {
      data.frame(Names = c("John", "Mary", "Charles", "Peter", "David", "Fabian", "Aggrey", "Elizabeth", "Anthony", "Catherine"), Amount = seq(from = 100000, by = 600, length.out = 10), Transaction.Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2016/1/1"), by = "quarter", length.out = 10))
    })


    Aged.Data <- eventReactive(input$Submit, {
      Debtors() %>% Aging(., Transaction.Date, input$Report.Date)
    })



  output$Aged.Data <- renderDataTable(Aged.Data())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The error I get is as below:

```
in recode term:  else = paste(year(input$Report.Date)-2, 'And Prior')
  message: Error in year(input$Report.Date) : object 'input' not found
```

This seems to be from the part where I'm calling my Aging function and trying to reference the input$Report.Date as an argument, i.e,

```
Aged.Data <- eventReactive(input$Submit, {
      Debtors() %>% Aging(., Transaction.Date, input$Report.Date)
```

I've tried looking online for a similar solution through questions like [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507359/unhandled-error-in-observer-object-input-not-found) and [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688665/object-input-not-found-r-shiny-app) and though the error is similar, the proposed methods of resolving them seem to be unique to those questions.

I will appreciate any assistance on this.

Joseph.

Comment: Try this: Aged.Data <- eventReactive(input$Submit, {
reportDate <- input$Report.Date
      Debtors() %>% Aging(., Transaction.Date, reportDate)

Comment: As an observation, when I use the `Aging` function without specifying the `Report.Date` parameter, the app works just fine, meaning that the `Aging` function is in order.

Comment: Thanks @Ika8, tried it but it throws the error that `in recode term:  else = paste(year(reportDate)-2, 'And Prior')
  message: Error in year(reportDate) : object 'reportDate' not found`

Comment: @ika8, when I use 'Aged.Data <- eventReactive(input$Submit, { 
      
      reportDate <<- input$Report.Date
    
      Debtors() %>% Aging(., Transaction.Date, reportDate)
    })' it works, but my worry with that is that any user can modify the `Report.Date` argument which will affect the output for other users.

Comment: You should NOT use <<- in that case..

Comment: Yes so, but when i don't use `<<-`, the `Aging` function does not see the `Report.Date` object, which is where I'm stuck. I even tried moving the `Aging` function inside the server function but it still failed, I still had to resort to the global assignment operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the combination of `deparse` and `substitute`.

Lets revisit what you are doing in simpler terms:

```
a <- function(val) {
  val <- deparse(substitute(val))
  val
}

b <- function() {
  c <- "someVariable"
  a(c)
}
```

With this setup you will get:

```
> b()
 [1] "c"
```

I hope you are aware of this and if not, make yourself. You basically are sending the variable name from the calling scope of `b` into the function scope of `a`. This is **almost never** what you want to happen in programming.

In your code sample, you are giving a variable *name* called `input$Report.Date` into the globally defined function `Aging` and you *hope* that it will be interpreted there in the right way. But of course, `input` is not an object in this function.

But why would it? Why do you have to interpret the variable in `Aging`. If you leave away the `deparse(substitute(...))`, you are not getting the *variable name* but the *variable value*. And nothing else is it that you want here.

I bet the `recode` function is to blame for you having to be aware of what is *code to be interpreted* and what are just *values*.

So the fix is to just leave away

```
Report.Date <- deparse(substitute(Report.Date))
```

---

Little Extra: If I were you, I would never use something like `deparse` and `substitute` unless there really is code involved that comes as plain text and must be interpreted.

Also `recode` seems to be so much over the line, since it just cloaks very simple modifications that you can easily do without this overcomplicated tool.

If I were you, my `Aging` function would look like this:

```
Aging <- function(data, dateColumnName, reportDate = Sys.Date()){
  if(missing(dateColumnName)) stop("You forgot to specify Transaction Date")

  maxDisplayYear <- year(reportDate) - 2
  data$Age <- year(data[,dateColumnName])
  data$Age[data$Age <= maxDisplayYear ] <- paste(maxDisplayYear, 'And Prior')

  return(data)
}
```

and you would call it in your example with

```
Debtors() %>% Aging("Transaction.Date", input$Report.Date)
```

Comment: thanks for this detailed answer, it helped me rethink how I'm creating functions. And yes, `recode` was to blame for my attempt to separate what code should be interpreted and what code should return values. Your simplified `Aging` function did the trick. Again, many thanks